# udf to parse string json in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which contains string json. Looks like below:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                        | 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"fields":{"list1":[{"list2":[{"list3":[{"type":false}]}]}]}}            | 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--
```

I wrote udfs to try to parse the json and then count the value that matches phone and return to a new column in df

```
def item_count(json,type):
    count=0
    for i in json.get("fields",{}).get("list1",[]):
        for j in i.get("list2",[]):
            for k in j.get("list3",[]):
                count+=k.get("type",None)==type
    return count

def item_phone_count(json):
    return item_count(json,False)

df2= df\
.withColumn('item_phone_count', (F.udf(lambda j: item_phone_count(json.loads(j)), t.StringType()))('col'))
```

But I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It looks like one of your variables in `item_count()` is `None`, but there is no way to figure out which one from the information you've posted. Please post the full error traceback and an [mcve] with enough information so that someone else can reproduce your error.

Comment: @craig you mean among i, j, k, one of them is none?

Comment: That is a possible cause of the error that you are seeing. Try printing them in the loop to see if one of them is `None`.

Comment: @Craig how can I print it since I am calling the udf from the pyspark dataframe?

Comment: @kihhfeue try to get a few entries from your dataframe and put them into the function manually and see what happens

Comment: @mck i checked the original json and some list3 are null. How can I deal with this situaion?

Comment: @kihhfeue see my answer below. basically you need to add checks for null/none.

Answer (score 1):

Check for none and skip those entries:

```
def item_count(json,type):
    count = 0
    if (json is None) or (json.get("fields",{}) is None):
        return count  
   
    for i in json.get("fields",{}).get("list1",[]):
        if i is None:
            continue
        for j in i.get("list2",[]):
            if j is None:
                continue 
            for k in j.get("list3",[]):
                if k is None:
                    continue 
                count += k.get("type",None) == type
    return count
```

Comment: the error is gone now but not sure why I still get 0 counts when I checked the original json and there is definitely value that matches the condition. Does json.load change the format of type?

Comment: I made some edit to the question. The type value is false